# How to flush a network stream when using network-conduit?

Tags: haskell, tcp, flush, conduit

I'm trying to use [network-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network-conduit/1.0.0/doc/html/Data-Conduit-Network.html) as a backend for (patched) HaskellNet's [IMAP](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/0.3.1/doc/html/Network-HaskellNet-IMAP.html). How can I force the conduit to flush the stream? This is a [required operation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/0.3.1/doc/html/Network-HaskellNet-BSStream.html#v%3absFlush), but it seems there is no such thing in network-conduit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

network-conduit should flush the stream every time you send it a `ByteString`, buffering is specifically *not* included as that would be handled by something like `blaze-builder-conduit` orthogonally. Are you seeing behavior which contradicts that?

Comment: Thank you, no, it's working as you describe. I just wanted to be sure that this is a guaranteed behavior, not just a coincidence.

Comment: Just to be sure, does sending a `ByteString` trigger calling "flush" at the OS level? So that it doesn't get buffered at the OS level? (It would be worth documenting the flushing behavior in the package docs.)

Comment: There isn't any buffering at the os level. network-conduit just uses sendAll under the surface: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.4.1.2/doc/html/Network-Socket-ByteString.html#v:sendAll

Comment: My bad, for some reason I thought sockets are also buffered to some extent. It turns out that actually [it's not possible to flush a TCP stream](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml).